# Tailwind and Alpine Show User List doesn't work with Alpine V3

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

I am trying to list a users from JSON data.
Alpine version@1.95 showing the user list
with AlpineV3 does not show the user list

I have created codepen link below

```html
<div x-data="userSearch()" x-init="fetchUser()" class="relative" x-cloak>
    <template x-if="users">
        <span class="px-3 py-3 text-gray-800 font-semibold text-md" x-text="`Users (${users.length})`"></span>
        <template x-for="(user,key) in users" :key="key">
            <div class="my-10 flex items-center relative">
                <img class="rounded-full w-20 h-20 bg-gray-800" :src="user.image" :alt="user.name" />
                <div class="p-0 flex grow flex-col items-center justify-start ml-4">
                    <h3 class="font-bold text-md pt-4 w-full" x-text="user.name"></h3>
                    <div class="w-full">
                        <span class="mb-4 px-4 rounded-full bg-sky-300" x-text="user.categort"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <button class="rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-white h-10 ml-4 px-6">
                    Invite
                </button> -->
                <div class="absolute top-50 right-0 text-gray-800 cursor-pointer"
                     x-on:click="user.show = !user.show">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                         id="_24x24_On_Light_Dots" data-name="24x24/On Light/Dots">
                        <rect id="view-box" width="24" height="24" fill="#141124" opacity="0" />
                        <path id="Shape"
                              d="M12,1.5A1.5,1.5,0,1,1,13.5,3,1.5,1.5,0,0,1,12,1.5Zm-6,0A1.5,1.5,0,1,1,7.5,3,1.5,1.5,0,0,1,6,1.5Zm-6,0A1.5,1.5,0,1,1,1.5,3,1.5,1.5,0,0,1,0,1.5Z"
                              transform="translate(4.5 11)" fill="#141124" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="absolute -right-40 -top-12 w-40 py-2 mt-2 bg-white bg-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-xl"
                     x-show.transition="user.show" @click.away="user.show = false">
                    <a href="#"
                       class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-300 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-400 hover:text-white">
                        Invite User
                    </a>
                    <a href="#"
                       class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-300 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-400 hover:text-white">
                        Mutals
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </template>
</div>
```

```js
const users =  [{"id":1,"name":"Kevina Easlea","email":"keaslea0@free.fr","gender":"Female","image":"https://robohash.org/inciduntmagnireprehenderit.png?size=400x498&set=set1","categort":"electronics"},
{"id":2,"name":"Dario D'Aulby","email":"ddaulby1@yahoo.com","gender":"Male","image":"https://robohash.org/utrepellendusassumenda.png?size=400x498&set=set1","categort":"home decor"}
}];
function userSearch() {
      return {
        // other default properties
        isLoading: false,
        users: null,
        options : null,
        search:"",
        fetchUser() {
          this.isLoading = true;
          this.users = users;
          
        }
      }
    }
```

V1.9.5 shows the list
[Alpine V1.9.5](https://codepen.io/B-L-Praveen/pen/WNYOpzK)
V3 does not show the List
[Alpine V3](https://codepen.io/B-L-Praveen/pen/zYMzZVv)

Why does `x-for` seem to not work with alpine V3?

Comment: When I manually added in the AlpineJS CDN with `defer` (as mentioned in the docs) instead of letting Codepen handle the CDN, it worked without having to change anything. Have you tried `defer`?

Answer (score 0):

As reported in the [Alpine.js documentation](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/if), in the last paragraph:

> Remember: <template> tags can only contain one root level element.

So, commenting out the *<span>* that displays user.length, (which maybe is just there for debugging) your code starts working:

```html
<div x-data="userSearch()" x-init="fetchUser()" class="relative" x-cloak>

    <template x-if="users">

        <!--span class="px-3 py-3 text-gray-800 font-semibold text-md" x-text="`Users (${users.length})`"></span-->

        <template x-for="(user,key) in users" :key="key">
```

If you need to keep the *<span>* you can wrap it together with the second *<template>* in another tag like a *<div>*

(In your code example there are also too many closing curly brackets, before the last closing square bracket, where you create the variable `const users = [{...`, but I think that's a typo)